# How to search-query ActiveRecord Associations (.joins) with SQL ILIKE

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to query multiple Active Record-Models by passing query-params to a Controller. Within my `tales_controller.rb` I have the following index-method:

```
def index
  @tales_count = Tale.all.count

  if params[:search]
    @tales = Tale.joins(:category)
                 .where('category.title ILIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%")
                 .where(
                   'title ILIKE :search OR
                   subtitle ILIKE :search OR
                   short_description ILIKE :search', search: "%#{params[:search]}%"
                  )
  else
    @tales = Tale.all
  end

  render template: 'tales/index'
end
```

Now, I can't seem to figure out the correct solution to this problem, as for the most part PG throws an error, saying: `PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "title" is ambiguous`. I sense that this is due to the fact that I try to query the title-field on the Tale-, as well as on the Category-Model. However I am not able to fix this problem myself.

By providing the index-method with the right queries I expect to be able to query a couple fields on the Tale-Model (namely `title`, `subtitle` and `short_description` and potentially more), as well as the `title`-field on the Category-Model.

The Category-Model is referenced by the Tale-Model. This is what the `schema.rb` looks like:

```
create_table "tales", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "public_id"
  t.string "title"
  t.string "subtitle"
  t.string "player_count"
  t.string "short_description"
  t.datetime "published_at"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.bigint "category_id"
  t.bigint "author_id"
  t.index ["author_id"], name: "index_tales_on_author_id"
  t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_tales_on_category_id"
end
```

EDIT: uhm, I just realized that by querying the way I currently do, I expect the `category.title` AND any of the other Tale-fields to carry the search-term. This is not want I intended, frankly.

Comment: Does `tales.title = ...` not help in the second `where` clause?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I tried that also

Comment: Is the name of the table `category` not `categories`? As in this line `.where('category.title `

Comment: Oh interesting, that solved the `ambiguous column` issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table name in Rails are by convention in the plural. So change this to read

```
.where('categories.title ILIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

and just for fun `ILIKE` in Postgres can be written as

```
.where('categories.title ~* ?', params[:search])
```